# how to pass parameters from RTK to Node (mysql connection)

Tags: mysql, reactjs, rtk-query

I've been trying for hours and I can't get it to work 100% correctly.

I've using RTK Query with a backend connection to a mysql server.

The issue is that I get all result and not from a specific query, no matter what param I use.

Let me explain:
in the backend (connection is working perfectly) part I have:

```
app.get("/test", (req, res) => {
    const q = 'select * from portfolios'
    db.query(q, (err, data) => {
        if(err) {return res.json(err)}
        return res.json(data)
    })
})
```

in the API-part, I have:

```
const testerApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'tester',
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
        baseUrl: "http://localhost:8800"
    }),
    endpoints(builder) {
        return {
            fetchTesting: builder.query({
                query: (name) => {
                    return {
                        url: '/test',
                        params: {
                            user_id: name.id 
                        },
                        method: 'GET',
                    };
                },
            }),
        };
    },

});
```

To call this, I use:

```
const name = {id:6, na:'iets'};
const results = useFetchTestingQuery(name);
```

but as a result, I get all content from the mysql test-table, it doesnt filter out the user-id.
So, the result always is something like this:

```
0
: 
{id: 1, user_id: 1, name: 'aaaaaa'}
1
: 
{id: 2, user_id: 1, name: 'bbbb'}
2
: 
{id: 3, user_id: 2, name: 'cccc'}
3
: 
{id: 9, user_id: 3, name: 'dddddd'}
...
```

So, it is partially working, but how can I get a filtered result?

This might sound a stupid question, but I am a beginner and I've been searching for hours to find a working solution.
I hope someone can help me a little bit ...

Thx,
Peter

tried many things, such as changing the bacnekd side to

```
app.get("/test/:user_id")
const q = 'select * from portfolios where user_id = ?'
    db.query(q, [user_id], (err, data) => {...
```

and many more but nothing seems to work.

Comment: At the end, I found a solution:
app.get("/test", (req, res) => {
const q = 'select * from test where user_id = ?'
db.query(q, [req.query.user_id], (err, data) => {
    if(err) {return res.json(err)}
    return res.json(data)
})

Is there an easier (and cleaner) solution than this or not?

Comment: That is the correct solution, it will not get cleaner - it is clean.